# IIS configuration for URL rewrite throwing Http404 error

Tags: asp.net, http, iis, https, iis-7

I am working on a website where I need a URL to be redirected from http to https. My URL looks like: (I generate this URL every time with random token ID)

http://testsite.local/login.aspx/activate?token=(random generated token id)

I want to redirect this URL to

https://testsite.local/login.aspx/activate?token=(random generated token id)

Below is the URL rewrite setting in IIS:

[image]

Web.config file:

```
 <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="http redirect">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
```

When I enter the URL I get to see Http404 error. To mention here - I checked off the 'SSL required' condition in IIS. I know that the matching pattern looks wrong but not sure about the fix. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your `{REQUEST_URI}` to `{R:1}` might solves this.

- {R:x} is used as back reference from the rule pattern ().

Works on my machine.

Like this:

```xml
<rule name="HTTPS rewrite" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true"> 
          <match url="(.*)"/>  
          <conditions> 
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$"/> 
          </conditions>  
          <action type="Rewrite" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{R:1}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
        </rule>
```

---

By the way, you mentioned that you need to `Redirect` HTTP traffic to HTTPS. But it seems your are trying to `Rewrite` HTTP traffic to HTTPS which works as a reverse proxy.

If you wanna configure a correct 301 HTTP redirect, please use `Redirect` instead of `Rewrite`.

Like this:

```xml
        <rule name="HTTPS force" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true"> 
          <match url="(.*)"/>  
          <conditions> 
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$"/> 
          </conditions>  
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent"/> 
        </rule>
```

Answer (score 1):

I followed the changes mentioned by @Anduin. Along with these changes, I created a port 80 binding for the site and the rule worked perfectly.